# json EOF error (End of file expected. json [Ln 2, Col 1])

Tags: python, json

I have been trying to create a subset of a json file,based on if certain relations exist.
Initially I thought there's something wrong with my python code.

```
import json

# Load the JSON file as a string
with open('train.json', 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
    data_str = f.read()

# Split the string into separate JSON objects
data_list = data_str.strip().split('\n')

# Load each JSON object separately
data = []
for obj in data_list:
    data.append(json.loads(obj))

# Create a new empty list to store the subset of data
subset = []

# Iterate through each entry in the data
for entry in data:

    # Iterate through the list of triples
    for triple in entry['triples']:

        # Check if the relation is one of the six relations
        if triple['relation'] == 'DATE_OF_BIRTH' or \
           triple['relation'] == 'RESIDENCE' or \
           triple['relation'] == 'BIRTHPLACE' or \
           triple['relation'] == 'NATIONALITY' or \
           triple['relation'] == 'EMPLOYEE_OF' or \
           triple['relation'] == 'EDUCATED_AT':

            # If the relation is one of the six relations, append the entry to the new list
            subset.append(entry)
            break

# Save the new list as a JSON file
with open('subset.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(subset, f)
```

But it turns out that the script is alright but there's Something wrong with the json file which I am not able to figure out.

The json file -

```
{"fold":3,"source":"Diffbot Knowledge Graph","documentId":"13205","documentText":"Documents Assist\n\nFlorida Cheap Divorce - Simple Divorce $280 flat fee - No Court Divorce\nEstablished in 2006.\nAfter a few years working as an Independent Associate of Legal Shield, formerly known as Pre-Paid Legal, Yamil Fuentes made it her mission to help her clients take advantage of their access to the legal system. After going through her own personal divorce she realized there was a need of affordable divorce services in the State of Florida.\nWhen she founded Apex Legal Document Preparation Services she became a Premium Member of the FALDP (Florida Association of Legal Document Preparers) and educated herself on the different types of divorce been offered across the State of Florida and learned from the best in the industry of legal document preparation services.\nThrough her membership she embarked on a journey to learn how to make the divorce process as easy as possible for her clients, making her company the most sought after divorce preparer in Florida touting the following service 'Express Divorce - 30 Days with No Court Hearing'.\nApex has now divorced hundreds of people.\nPassionate about divorcing people in the quickest and less painful manner. She has mastered the art of preparing any type of divorce in the State of Florida. Many of her clients are in the South Florida area but she is not limited to these clients.","passages":[{"passageId":"13205:453:779","exhaustivelyAnnotatedProperties":[{"propertyId":"9","propertyName":"EDUCATED_AT","propertyDescription":"Describes the relationship between a person and the institution where she/he studied."}],"passageStart":453,"passageEnd":779,"passageText":"When she founded Apex Legal Document Preparation Services she became a Premium Member of the FALDP (Florida Association of Legal Document Preparers) and educated herself on the different types of divorce been offered across the State of Florida and learned from the best in the industry of legal document preparation services.","facts":[]}]}
{"fold":2,"source":"Diffbot Knowledge Graph","documentId":"7","documentText":"Tata Chemicals Europe\n\nTata Chemicals Europe (formerly Brunner Mond (UK) Limited) is a UK-based chemicals company that is a subsidiary of Tata Chemicals Limited, itself a part of the India-based Tata Group. Its principal products are soda ash, sodium bicarbonate, calcium chloride and associated alkaline chemicals.","passages":[{"passageId":"7:23:206","exhaustivelyAnnotatedProperties":[{"propertyId":"1","propertyName":"SUBSIDIARY_OF","propertyDescription":"Describes the relationship between a parent company and one of its subsidiaries."}],"passageStart":23,"passageEnd":206,"passageText":"Tata Chemicals Europe (formerly Brunner Mond (UK) Limited) is a UK-based chemicals company that is a subsidiary of Tata Chemicals Limited, itself a part of the India-based Tata Group.","facts":[{"factId":"7:23:44:138:160:1","propertyId":"1","humanReadable":"<Tata Chemicals Europe> <SUBSIDIARY_OF> <Tata Chemicals Limited>","annotatedPassage":"<Tata Chemicals Europe> (formerly Brunner Mond (UK) Limited) is a UK-based chemicals company that is a subsidiary of <Tata Chemicals Limited>, itself a part of the India-based Tata Group.","subjectStart":23,"subjectEnd":44,"subjectText":"Tata Chemicals Europe","subjectUri":"","objectStart":138,"objectEnd":160,"objectText":"Tata Chemicals Limited","objectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2331365"},{"factId":"7:162:168:183:205:1","propertyId":"1","humanReadable":"<itself> <SUBSIDIARY_OF> <India-based Tata Group>","annotatedPassage":"Tata Chemicals Europe (formerly Brunner Mond (UK) Limited) is a UK-based chemicals company that is a subsidiary of Tata Chemicals Limited, <itself> a part of the <India-based Tata Group>.","subjectStart":162,"subjectEnd":168,"subjectText":"itself","subjectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2331365","objectStart":183,"objectEnd":205,"objectText":"India-based Tata Group","objectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q331715"},{"factId":"7:114:118:138:160:1","propertyId":"1","humanReadable":"<that> <SUBSIDIARY_OF> <Tata Chemicals Limited>","annotatedPassage":"Tata Chemicals Europe (formerly Brunner Mond (UK) Limited) is a UK-based chemicals company <that> is a subsidiary of <Tata Chemicals Limited>, itself a part of the India-based Tata Group.","subjectStart":114,"subjectEnd":118,"subjectText":"that","subjectUri":"","objectStart":138,"objectEnd":160,"objectText":"Tata Chemicals Limited","objectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2331365"},{"factId":"7:55:80:138:160:1","propertyId":"1","humanReadable":"<Brunner Mond (UK) Limited> <SUBSIDIARY_OF> <Tata Chemicals Limited>","annotatedPassage":"Tata Chemicals Europe (formerly <Brunner Mond (UK) Limited>) is a UK-based chemicals company that is a subsidiary of <Tata Chemicals Limited>, itself a part of the India-based Tata Group.","subjectStart":55,"subjectEnd":80,"subjectText":"Brunner Mond (UK) Limited","subjectUri":"","objectStart":138,"objectEnd":160,"objectText":"Tata Chemicals Limited","objectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2331365"},{"factId":"7:23:44:162:168:1","propertyId":"1","humanReadable":"<Tata Chemicals Europe> <SUBSIDIARY_OF> <itself>","annotatedPassage":"<Tata Chemicals Europe> (formerly Brunner Mond (UK) Limited) is a UK-based chemicals company that is a subsidiary of Tata Chemicals Limited, <itself> a part of the India-based Tata Group.","subjectStart":23,"subjectEnd":44,"subjectText":"Tata Chemicals Europe","subjectUri":"","objectStart":162,"objectEnd":168,"objectText":"itself","objectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2331365"},{"factId":"7:138:160:183:205:1","propertyId":"1","humanReadable":"<Tata Chemicals Limited> <SUBSIDIARY_OF> <India-based Tata Group>","annotatedPassage":"Tata Chemicals Europe (formerly Brunner Mond (UK) Limited) is a UK-based chemicals company that is a subsidiary of <Tata Chemicals Limited>, itself a part of the <India-based Tata Group>.","subjectStart":138,"subjectEnd":160,"subjectText":"Tata Chemicals Limited","subjectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2331365","objectStart":183,"objectEnd":205,"objectText":"India-based Tata Group","objectUri":"http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q331715"}]}]}
{"fold":1,"source":"Diffbot Knowledge Graph","documentId":"29726","documentText":"Morphine\n\nMorphine was an American alternative rock group formed by Mark Sandman, Dana Colley, and Jerome Deupree in Cambridge, Massachusetts in 1989. After five successful albums and extensive touring, they disbanded after lead vocalist Sandman died of a heart attack onstage in Palestrina, Italy, on July 3, 1999. Founding members have reformed into the band Vapors of Morphine, maintaining much of the original style and sound.","passages":[{"passageId":"29726:151:315","exhaustivelyAnnotatedProperties":[{"propertyId":"14","propertyName":"DATE_OF_DEATH","propertyDescription":"Describes the date of death of a person."}],"passageStart":151,"passageEnd":315,"passageText":"After five successful albums and extensive touring, they disbanded after lead vocalist Sandman died of a heart attack onstage in Palestrina, Italy, on July 3, 1999.","facts":[{"factId":"29726:238:245:302:314:14","propertyId":"14","humanReadable":"<Sandman> <DATE_OF_DEATH> <July 3, 1999>","annotatedPassage":"After five successful albums and extensive touring, they disbanded after lead vocalist <Sandman> died of a heart attack onstage in Palestrina, Italy, on <July 3, 1999>.","subjectStart":238,"subjectEnd":245,"subjectText":"Sandman","subjectUri":"","objectStart":302,"objectEnd":314,"objectText":"July 3, 1999","objectUri":""}]}]}
```

I have to create a subset of the json file.

Comment: Something's off with your example. For example, you want to iterate over `'triples'`, but `'triples'` is not a key in the JSON content that you posted (in fact, "triples" is not contained in the posted JSON content, at all). Please be sure that your posted code and data is sufficient to reproduce the problem that you describe.

Comment: Your code does not seem to match your example data in any manner. Perhaps you pasted the wrong data.